# Why do objects move apart, although they should move toward each other?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm tired...
I'm tried to make a simple 2d planetary shooter and started from creating my own physic with Newton's law of universal gravitation(something like that), but my code isn't working - bodies moves from each other, while they Colliders is colliding, and I don't know why.(even inertia)
So, I've tried to capy and paste code from another StackOverflow, but its not working too. Requesting some help!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvvBs.jpg

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(CircleCollider2D), typeof(CircleCollider2D))]
public class MassEffect : MonoBehaviour
{
    //public GameObject player;
    private float gRadius = 5f;
    public float rotSpeed = 0.5f;
    public float gravitation = 50f;




    private HashSet<Rigidbody2D> affectedBodies = new HashSet<Rigidbody2D>();
    private Rigidbody2D componentRigidbody;
    private CircleCollider2D gTrigger;

    private void Start()
    {
        componentRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        gTrigger = GetComponents<CircleCollider2D>()[1];
        gTrigger.isTrigger = true;
        gTrigger.radius = gRadius / transform.localScale.x;
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        var rbInRadius = other.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        if (rbInRadius != null)
        {
            affectedBodies.Add(rbInRadius);
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        var rbInRadius = other.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        if (rbInRadius != null)
        {
            affectedBodies.Remove(rbInRadius);
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {    

        transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * rotSpeed);

        foreach (var objectInVicinity in affectedBodies)
        {
            if (objectInVicinity == null)
            {
                affectedBodies.Remove(objectInVicinity);
                break;
            }

            float dist = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, objectInVicinity.transform.position);
            float gravitationFactor = 1 - dist / gRadius;
            Vector2 force = (transform.position - objectInVicinity.transform.position).normalized * gravitation * gravitationFactor;
            objectInVicinity.AddForce(force);
        }
    }
    void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, gRadius);
    }
}
```

Comment: How exactly is the second code you're now using not working?

Comment: I've added a link to gif. My code is working vice versa - he forcing object from each other.